# How to test RxJs WebSocket in Jasmine

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

There is a service that manages WebSocket messages and I need to test it without workarounds for TypeScript (websocket is a private property so that no one is able to access websocket directly).

Socket connection is established using WebSocket from RxJs.

`this.socket = new WebSocket(uri);`.

How do I test if my service logic works right with socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since RxJs uses WebSocket internally which is a function it's easy to mock in next way

```
const mockSocket: WebSocket = {
  send: createSpy('WebSocket#send'),
} as any;

spyOn(window, 'WebSocket').and.returnValue(
  mockSocket
);
```

Now to test the logic of a socket handling it's required to simply call callbacks which are established by RxJs.

(inside test with `fakeAsync`)

```
service.sendLargeString('string').subscribe();
tick(10);

// Mock socket opening event
mockSocket.onopen({} as any);

// Some expectations towards "send" messages
expect(mockSocket.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith('send');
tick(10);

// Mock socket closing event
mockSocket.onclose({} as any);
```